# OAuth2 - Where did ClientSecret go?

Tags: asp.net, google-api, google-calendar-api, dotnetopenauth

I'm trying to write an `ASP.NET` application that uses the Google Calendar Service. To do so, I'm using the example shown [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Tasks.ASP.NET.SimpleOAuth2/Default.aspx.cs?repo=samples).

This is a TasksService application, but the methods should be pretty much the same.

It seems though, that this application uses an older version of `DotNetOpenAuth`, in which the ClientBase interface had a ClientSecret property. In the new version they removed this propery.

Where did this property go?

It is mandatory for the authorization process

Comment: I ended up using the Google API version of DotNetOpenAuth (It is included in the ZIP under ThirdParty). This fixed all compatibility issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ClientSecret` property was replaced with the `ClientCredentialApplicator` property (and constructor parameter). This gives you the freedom to express not only the secret, but how it should be communicated (via form POST parameter or HTTP Authorization header).